# EF Core Cascading Referential Integrity with DeleteBehavior.Restrict does not work well

Tags: ef-core-3.1

I have one sql server database created with code first. There are two tables that have a one to many relationship. The database works and is created well.
In sql server if I try to delete one of the classification records, I get an error (referencial integrity restriction). This is how I want it to work. But in ef core, if I delete one classification `dbset.Remove(classification)`, the classification is deleted and the classification in the customer is set to `null`.
I think this is how it should work for `DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull`.
There is a note "**Changes in EF Core 2.0**" in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete that explains the DeleteBehavior function.

```
I have the next records:
Classification:
Id      Name
1       General
2       Others
Customers:
Id      Name        IdClassification
1       Customer A  1
2       Customer B  2
3       Customer C  <null>

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    public int? IdClassification { get; set; }
    public Classification Classification { get; set; }
}

public class Classification
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    public ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Classification> Classifications { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Classification>(
        entity => 
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>(
        entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.IdClassification);
            ...
            // Claves foráneas
            entity.HasOne(c => c.Classification)
                .WithMany(x => x.Customers)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.IdClassification)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Customer_Classification");
        });
    }
}
```

Is there a way to prevent deletion of classification records in ef core? (I don't want to check if there is any customer record that is linked to the classification because I have to use the classification with more tables).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core 3.0 added several new values to the `DeleteBehavior` enum - `ClientCascade`, `NoAction`, `ClientNoAction`. Unfortunately the documentation is not updated (except for  enum values in API reference), and only the `ClientNoAction` is mentioned in the 3.0 Breaking Changes - [DeleteBehavior.Restrict has cleaner semantics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#deletebehaviorrestrict-has-cleaner-semantics):

> **Old behavior**
>
> Before 3.0, `DeleteBehavior.Restrict` created foreign keys in the database with `Restrict` semantics, but also changed internal fixup in a non-obvious way.
>
> **New behavior**
>
> Starting with 3.0, `DeleteBehavior.Restrict` ensures that foreign keys are created with `Restrict` semantics--that is, no cascades; throw on constraint violation--without also impacting EF internal fixup.
>
> **Why**
>
> This change was made to improve the experience for using `DeleteBehavior` in an intuitive manner, without unexpected side-effects.
>
> **Mitigations**
>
> The previous behavior can be restored by using `DeleteBehavior.ClientNoAction`.

More info is contained in the associated tracking issue - [12661: Update DeleteBehavior to be more consistent and understandable](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12661)

Honestly even after reading all that, I don't find it cleaner, but even more confusing. `Restrict` seems to be obsoleted and replaced with `NoAction`, which regardless of what have been said actually *does* set loaded related entities navigation property/FK to `null`, thus causing `SET NULL` database behavior as you already experienced.

After trying all of them, the only option which does what you expect is the aforementioned [ClientNoAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.deletebehavior?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DeleteBehavior_ClientNoAction):

> Note: it is unusual to use this value. Consider using `ClientSetNull` instead to match the behavior of EF6 with cascading deletes disabled.
>
> For entities being tracked by the `DbContext`, the values of foreign key properties in dependent entities are not changed when the related principal entity is deleted. This can result in an inconsistent graph of entities where the values of foreign key properties do not match the relationships in the graph.
>
> If the database has been created from the model using Entity Framework Migrations or the `EnsureCreated()` method, then the behavior in the database is to generate an error if a foreign key constraint is violated.

regardless of their note at the beginning.

---

With all that being said, simply replace `Restrict` with `ClientNoAction` and the issue will be solve. No database migration is needed because this change affects only the client behavior.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thank you very much, this works as I wanted. Referential integrity in sql server and in ef core work correctly. I've tried it first without having to do the migration and then starting the migration, and in both cases it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the classification entity needs correct initialization, suppose to delete restriction rule.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Classification>()
    .HasKey(e => e.Id)
    .HasMany(e => e.Customers)
    .WithOne(e => e.Classification)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
    .IsRequired(true);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried Ivan's solution first and it works fine. Thank you.